# Calculating the expected number of items shared by chance in a Venn Diagram

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

I have a Venn Diagram that looks like this:

> $$A) \, 213 \quad B) \, 160 \quad A\cap B) \, 100$$

The items from $A$ come from a population where their probability to be selected is $\frac{313}{12800}$.

The items from $B$ come from a population where their probability to be selected is $\frac{260}{1407}$.

How can I calculate a null model that tells me the number of shared items expected by chance if I create a Venn diagram for that data?

Comment: Presumably the $213$ items are $A$ and not $B$ and the $160$ are $B$ and not $A$.  However normally you would have one population, some of which has characteristic $A$ and some of which has characteristic $B$.  Then the population outside both $A$ and $B$ would be the rest of the universe, here everything except $473$.  Is that $12327$ or $934$?

Comment: The items (313 and 260) are expressed genes in a given condition. And the totals (12800 and 1407) are total sampled genes. What I want to prove is if this A & B is not a product of chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ were independent, you would expect the same fraction of $B$'s to have $A$ as the whole population.  Of the $260 B$'s, $100$ are also $A$'s, about $38\%$.  But of the whole population, $A$'s are rare-a little less than $4\%$.  Similarly the other way around.  They are far from independent.

Comment: I would like to use a statistical test. Do you think a Fisher Test (observed vs expected) will suffice?